# How can i change OneDrive folder location in Win7 to point to MyDocuments

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders, onedrive

The default folder of OneDrive is this

> C:\Users\myUser\Documents\OneDrive

and i would like to change where it points to this path:

> C:\Users\myUser\Documents

How can i do it in **Win7**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to do it with the OneDrive desktop client's interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to change the location of the OneDrive folder, then you have to do that through the desktop client interface. If you are wanting to sync a folder other than the OneDrive one, you won't be able to. OneDrive will only sync what is in the OneDrive folder.

If you want to sync your Documents folder, you can:

- Place a copy of Documents in the OneDrive folder
- Redirect Documents to inside the OneDrive folder

  - Right click on Documents folder
  - Click on Properties
  - Click the Location tab, then click on Move
  - Select inside the OneDrive folder

Comment: I'm in a situation where I must use option `2. Redirect...` problem is the folder I want to sync is in ``C:\`` so the Location tab doesn't show. How do I proceed? Or do I need to manually copy the folder anytime there is a modification?

Answer (score 0):

To change the default "Documents" location to OneDrive:

1. Right-click on your PC's "Documents" folder
2. Select "Properties"
3. Click on the default address and "Remove" each one until they're all removed
4. Click "Include a folder"
5. Select your "Documents" folder in OneDrive
6. Click "OK"

You have changed the default location. Do the same for your pictures and movies folders