# Windows 10: Enabling Documents folder as default for storing and saving user data

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive, gaming, my-documents

Right now, default space which Windows 10 tells the programs to use it as (My) Documents folder is **C:\Users\haa_admin\OneDrive\اسناد**. (Documents folder is not shown in File Explorer) This has made problems for some of my old games which use (My) Documents folder as the default space for saving progress. Because they are old and they don't know anything about OneDrive and Persian (اسناد means documents) so they do not know where to put their saving folder.
([My first question describing this problem earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/1527021/windows-10-games-are-not-saved?noredirect=1#comment2315098_1527021))

I know that this happened because when I was installing Windows somehow I let OneDrive to take care of my libraries and personal folders instead of "This PC Only" but right now, OneDrive is no longer exists on my PC. I have uninstalled it, yet it has messed things up as I described above.

I googled a bit and I found this:

[Documents folder missing under "This PC" Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/documents-folder-missing-under-this-pc-windows-10/3ec6337b-8190-41f5-8bec-b948b0fa72e4)

It says that in OneDrive settings I can give the control back to "This PC" but as I said earlier, I have uninstalled OneDrive.

How can I fix this? How can I set C:\Users\haa_admin\Documents as default and remove these leftovers of OneDrive?

*Tip 1*: I am using an user-named account which has administrative rights.

*Tip 2*: Default system and display language is English, not Persian and I never changed it since installing Windows.

Tip 3: The abandoned C:\Users\haa_admin\Documents has no LOCATION tab under its properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i change OneDrive folder location in Win7 to point to MyDocuments](https://superuser.com/questions/724964/how-can-i-change-onedrive-folder-location-in-win7-to-point-to-mydocuments)

Comment: You should have simply disabled the setting within OneDrive instead of uninstalling OneDrive on Windows 10.  The duplicate question's accepted answer indicates how you can move the Documents folder to a new location.

Comment: @Ramhound No, it does not. My games are searching for User/Documents not User/OneDrive/Documents. It does not work, I have tried it, already.

Comment: You have viewed the properties of the Documents folder and moved it to a new location?  The entire point of moving the files properly is to update the registry.  After you change the location you can move it back to any location you want after you log out of your user profile.  *Knowing everything I know about Windows, which is based on decades of experience, I stand by my decision to flag as a duplicate.* I highly recommend you reinstall OneDrive then disable the OneDrive feature. By uninstalling OneDrive you have put yourself in a position of having to hack together a solution and thats bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/857487/how-do-i-prevent-windows-from-resetting-my-default-documents-folder-to-onedrive?rq=1

Comment: You made no mention of that fact in your question.  I can only go off what your question states.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited Tip 3

Answer (score 3):

The Documents folder needs to be set in two places.

First, use `regedit` to navigate to the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`,
and set the value named `Personal` to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`.

Logout and login back, then navigate to the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`.
The value named `Personal` should read
`C:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents`.
If this is not the case, set it to the above value.

Logout and login back, or even reboot, to see if those modifications are now
effective.
If this is not the case, then there exists a deeper problem on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell:

```
$USF = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'

Remove-ItemProperty -Path $USF -Name '{f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756}'

Set-ItemProperty -Path $USF -Name 'Personal' -Value 'C:\Users\haa_admin\Documents'
gps explorer | spps
```

That should set your designated **Doucuments** folder as 'C:\Users\haa_admin\Documents'